# Application relies on Python 3, system uses Python 2. How to fix this?

Tags: python, versions, python3

This issue that I have is causing an application (MySQL Workbench) to run UNsmoothly.  Basically, after I upgraded MySQL I had problems connecting to a database through SSH.

It was suggested that this issue has to do with Python running version 2.7, but having Workbench rely on Python 3; and it was confirmed by another similar case.  To see more, go [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27070957/database-ssh-connection-cannot-be-established-from-workbench/27332781#27332781).

So I'd like to know if I can have Python 3 running as default.  Let me know if I can give more information that is useful.

Comment: Can you use a shebang line (e.g. `#!/usr/bin/python3`) at the start of your script? That could work if the script is executed directly but not if the user runs `python yourscript.py`.

Comment: Would this be the script that the application runs?  Where can I look for it?

Comment: Sorry, I was under the impression that you had created a python script that needed to run with python3. The shebang may have worked there.

Comment: Does the solution on [this page](http://bugs.mysql.com/bug.php?id=74960) (i.e. downgrading paramiko) work for you? Might be worth checking what version you've got installed and if it's the same as the one in the bug report try downgrading.